# Аргументы при запуске тестов(выбор браузера, окружения)Selenium+Pytest

Tags: selenium, pytest

друзья! Я начинающий auto qa, просьба подсказать, как вы при запуске тестов, указываете адрес разных окружений(дев,тест,прод) а так же версию браузера.

Я использую сторонний модуль args, вроде у селениума есть свои опции(parser.addoption("--browser", action="store") как-то так вроде)

И ли вы гоняете тесты на одном браузере?

conftest.py:

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver

@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def browser():
    print("\nstart browser for test..")
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe')
    browser.implicitly_wait(200)
    yield browser
    print("\nquit browser..")
    browser.quit()
```

UPD: с аргументами запуска разных браузеров - разобрался. Как запускать теперь на разных урлах?

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from os import getenv
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--browser_name', action='store', default='chrome',
                     help="Choose browser: chrome or firefox")
    parser.addoption('--url', action='store', default='http://google.ru',
                     help="Choose lang")

@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def browser(request):
    browser_name = request.config.getoption("browser_name")
    url = request.config.getoption("url")
    if browser_name == "chrome":
        print("\nstart browser for test..")
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe')
        browser.implicitly_wait(200)


    elif browser_name == "firefox":
        browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\\Selenium\\geckodriver.exe')
        browser.implicitly_wait(200)
    

    yield browser
    print("\nquit browser..")
    browser.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен:
импортируется значение переменной из созданного файла. Ручками перед раном, это значение корректируется